# 'tuple' object is not callable - Pygame

Tags: python

I have, yet again, run into a problem while coding a game in pygame.

While dealing with the function that allows the player to shoot, I keep getting this error: 'tuple' object is not callable'

In my main program, the 'loop' subroutine:

```
play=True

    sprites,platforms,player1=GameClass.Game.run('')  # Player 1 is defined here.

    display.fill(WHITE)
    GameClass.Game.restart(player1)
    display.fill(WHITE)


    while play:
        display.fill(WHITE)
        GameClass.Game.getevent(player1)
        platforms.draw(display)
        sprites.draw(display)
        pygame.display.update()

        collision=pygame.sprite.spritecollide(player1,platforms, False)
        if collision:
            player1.updateposition(True,False)

        else:
            player1.updateposition(False,False)
```

As you can see, player1 is defined. I then call GameClass.Game.getevent, which has self as a parameter.

I pass player 1 through the code and get to this line:

```
if event.type==pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button==1:
                    PlayerClasses.Player.shoot(self)
```

As self is still assigned to player1, it moves through to the final section, the bullet class.

```
class Bullet(pygame.sprite.Sprite):

    def __init__(self,speed,Game):

        self.speed=speed
        self.image=pygame.Surface((10,10))
        self.rect=self.image.get_rect()
        #self.x,self.y=Player.exportlocation(player1)

    def movebullet(self):
        self.rect.center((self.x+self.speed),self.y)
```

I get the error:

(There is more up here if needed)

```
 File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\Base.py", line 293, in loop
    GameClass.Game.getevent(player1)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\GameClass.py", line 64, in getevent
    PlayerClasses.Player.shoot(self)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\PlayerClasses.py", line 77, in shoot
    Bullet.movebullet(self)
  File "C:\Users\Luke\Desktop\Year13CA\PlayerClasses.py", line 96, in movebullet
    self.rect.center((self.x+self.speed),self.y)
TypeError: 'tuple' object is not callable
```

I do not know why this problem occurs.

Many thanks,
Luke

Comment: It appears as though `self.rect.center` is a tuple, not a function.

Comment: Where is `self.rect.center` defined?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It happens because of `self.rect.center(...)`. `self.rect.center` is presumably a tuple. You probably want to assign it instead, with `self.rect.center = ...`.

Answer (score 0):

From [the FineManual](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/rect.html) (emphasis is mine):

> The Rect object has several virtual attributes which can be used to
>   move and align the Rect:
>
> x,y top, left, bottom, right topleft, bottomleft, topright,
>   bottomright midtop, midleft, midbottom, midright
>   **center**, centerx, centery size, width, height w,h
>
> **All of these attributes can be assigned to:**
>
> rect1.right = 10
>
> **rect2.center = (20,30)**